# How to chunk a stream of objects?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a stream of objects (`objectMode: true`) and want to chunk it into arrays of equal size, so that I can pipe them to another function that accepts arrays. I found the following modules that seem to accomplish that for buffers, but not for objects:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/block-stream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chunkit
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chunking-streams
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixed-chunk-stream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/chunk-stream

Do you know of a module that can do this for object streams or is there an obvious simple DIY solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following to work:

```
function ItemCollector (chunkSize) {

  this._buffer = [];
  this._chunkSize = chunkSize;

  stream.Transform.call(this, { objectMode: true });
}

util.inherits(ItemCollector, stream.Transform);

ItemCollector.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {

  if (this._buffer.length == this._chunkSize) {

    this.push(this._buffer);
    this._buffer = [];
  }

  this._buffer.push(chunk);

  done();
};

ItemCollector.prototype._flush = function () {

  this.push(this._buffer);
};
```

Use like this:

```
objectStream.pipe(new ItemCollector(10)).pipe(otherFunction)
```

Comment: To note, `_flush` also takes a `done` parameter that needs to be called for the stream to properly complete.